# Connect Azure Iot Hub message route with Azure function Event Hub

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

Is it possible to connect a message route set as event to an azure function. I have only managed to connect to event hub compatible endpoint but not with a specific message route

I have set "EventHubName": "messages/events/valid-route" in function.json

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function.json should look like this for getting messages from a route. You have to define the route in the path setting

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "events",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "%EventHubName%",
      "connection": "IoTHubTriggerConnection",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default",
      "path": "valid-route"
    }
  ]
}
```